# Tkinter: how to allow column selection in text widget?

Tags: events, widget, tkinter

Is there away to override the default "drag to select" behaviour in Tkinter text widget to allow column selection?
I'd like the user to point mouse, press left button and move while holding left button to select in column mode. With the default behaviour selection is line oriented.
I'd like something like vim column mode.

Thank you,
L-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. In short, with the proper hotkeys held down, when LMB is pressed the last known `insert` position is recorded as `boxstart`. As the mouse moves the current `insert` position is recorded as `boxend`. `boxend` and `boxstart` are compiled into essentially an extended `bbox`, in the format `(min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row, width, height)`. Those ranges are iterated and a custom tag is applied, while **all** other tags are entirely suppressed. If a line is not long enough to allow a proper box shape, spaces are added to the end of the line. As you drag the mouse **all** changes from the last box are removed, and this explanation starts again. When you release any of the hotkeys **all** tags are unsuppressed and `tk.SEL` replaces all of the ranges from our custom tag. Any action that results in deselection will remove **all** changes the final box-select created.

For deeper knowledge refer to the code. I commented almost every line. The meat-and-potatoes of the code is in the `__box(action)`, `__handler` and `cut/copy/paste` methods.

**how to use:**

Put the caret where you want the selection to start. Then **Shift+Alt+LMB+DRAG** to box-select or **Shift+Alt+LMB** where you want the selection to end. You can select in any direction. Cut, Copy, Paste and Drag/Drop of any kind of selection are built in. Drag/Drop of a **box-selection** uses horizontal grab offsets. So, if you grab a **box-selection** (ex) 2 lines from the top of the selection, you have to drop it 2 lines lower than you want it to appear. The only time a regular selection is not sent off to built-in behavior is when it is being dragged/dropped. Regular selections do not use any offsets for Drag/Drop.

```py
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.font as tkf
from collections import namedtuple
from typing      import Iterable, Any
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import math

# event.state flags
SHIFT   = 0x000001
CONTROL = 0x000004 
BUTTON1 = 0x000100
ALT     = 0x020000

# marks
INSPNT  = 'insertpoint'

# begin col/row, end col/row, (width or len), height
SelectBounds = namedtuple('SelectBounds', 'bc br ec er w h')


@dataclass 
class Text_t:
    font            :str  = '{Courier New} 14'
    selectforeground:str  = '#222222'
    selectbackground:str  = '#DDDDDD'
    wrap            :str  = "none"
    exportselection :int  = 1
    takefocus       :int  = 1
    undo            :bool = True
    autoseparators  :bool = True
    maxundo         :int  = 32 #-1 for infinite

class Text(tk.Text):
    # CARET POSITIONING
    @property
    def caret(self) -> str:
        return self.index('insert')

    @caret.setter
    def caret(self, index:str) -> None:
        self.mark_set('insert', index)
        self.focus_set()
     
    #GEOMETRY
    #absolutely do NOT convert anything within this method to an `.index(...)`
    #some of the descriptions below may not exist yet
    def __bounds(self, b:str=None, e:str=None, ow:bool=False) -> SelectBounds:
        b, e = b or self.__boxstart, e or self.__boxend
        #parse row/col positions
        b_ = map(int, b.split('.')) 
        e_ = map(int, e.split('.')) 
        
        if self.__boxselect:
            #row and col positions ~ min/max each
            (br,er),(bc,ec) = (sorted(x) for x in zip(b_,e_))
            #width, height 
            w, h = ec-bc, er-br
        #regular selection
        else:
            #row and col positions ~ min/max row
            (br,bc),(er,ec) = b_, e_
            (br,er)         = sorted((br,er))
            #len, height 
            w, h = len(self.get(f'{br}.{bc}', f'{er}.{ec}')), er-br
            
        #overwrite    
        if ow:
            self.__boxstart = f'{br}.{bc}'
            self.__boxend   = f'{er}.{ec}'
        
        #technically, `h` is always 1 less than the actual height
        #it's ok because everything starts by considering the first line
        #i.e. first_selected_line_number + `h` = the correct last line number
        return SelectBounds(bc, br, ec, er, w, h) 
      
    #convenient
    def dlineinfo(self, index=tk.INSERT) -> tuple:
        self.update_idletasks()
        return super().dlineinfo(index)
    
    #TAGS
    # No exception .start, .end
    def tag_bounds(self, tag:str) -> tuple:
        if (tr:=self.tag_ranges(tag)) and len(tr)>1: 
            return map(str,(tr[0],tr[-1]))
        return None, None
       
    #replace all instances of `tag_in` with `tag_out`
    def tag_replace(self, tag_in:str, tag_out:str) -> None:
        r = self.tag_ranges(tag_in)
        #swap the tags
        for i in range(0, len(r), 2):
            self.tag_remove(tag_in , *r[i:i+2])
            self.tag_add   (tag_out, *r[i:i+2])
        #ensure the widget's full attention ~ it can get froggy
        self.focus_set()
           
    #remove all instances of a tag, and reassign it by `b` and `e` accordingly
    def tag_move(self, tag:str, b:Iterable=None, e:Iterable=None) -> None:
        x, y = self.tag_bounds(tag)
        
        if x and y: self.tag_remove(tag, x, y)
        
        if b and e:
            x = b if isinstance(b, (list,tuple)) else (b,)
            y = e if isinstance(e, (list,tuple)) else (e,)
            for b, e in zip(x,y):
                self.tag_add(tag, b, e)

    #TEXT
    #replace text ~ convenient, maybe
    def replace_text(self, b:str, e:str, text:str) -> None:
        self.delete(b, e)
        self.insert(b, text)
    
    #CONSTRUCTOR
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **{**asdict(Text_t()), **kwargs})
        
        #box-select tag
        self.tag_configure('BOXSELECT' , background=self['selectbackground'])
        
        #selection insertion point
        self.mark_set(INSPNT, '1.0')
        self.mark_gravity(INSPNT, tk.LEFT)
        
        #add listeners
        for evt in ('KeyPress','KeyRelease','ButtonPress-1','ButtonRelease-1','<Paste>'): 
            self.bind(f'<{evt}>', self.__handler)
        
        #features
        self.__boxselect   = False  #select text within a rect
        self.__boxcopy     = False  #cut/copy/paste with column behavior
        self.__seldrag     = False  #drag any selected data to a new location
        #vars
        self.__hotbox      = False  #shift and alt are pressed
        self.__mouseisdown = False  #locks in box-select begin col and begin row bounds
        self.__boxstart    = None   #box bounds start position
        self.__boxend      = None   #box bounds end position
        self.__hgrabofs    = None   #horizontal offset from 'current' to sel.start
        self.__linsert     = None   #last known 'insert' position ~ only used while self.__hotbox is True
        self.__lbounds     = None   #last bounds that were applied
        self.__lclipbd     = ''     #back-up of last clipboard data
        
        #hijack tcl commands stream so we can pinpoint various commands
        name = str(self)
        self.__pxy = name + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", name, self.__pxy)
        self.tk.createcommand(name, self.__proxy)
    
    #PROXY
    def __proxy(self, cmd, *args) -> Any:
        #suppress ALL tags except BOXSELECT from the moment the mouse is pressed
        #for hotkeys and dragging
        if (self.__hotbox or self.__seldrag) and (cmd=='tag') and args:
            if args[0] in ('add', 'remove'):
                if args[1]!='BOXSELECT':
                    return
         
        #proceed as normal
        try             : target = self.tk.call((self.__pxy, cmd) + args)#;print(cmd, args)
        except Exception: return
        
        return target   
    
    #BOXSELECT
    #swap BOXSELECT for tk.SEL and config
    def __hotswap(self) -> None:
        #unsuppresses all tags in .__proxy
        self.__hotbox      = False          
        #this is a box-select state
        #regardless of what the actual state of the mouse is
        self.__mouseisdown = False 
        #replace BOXSELECT tags with tk.SEL
        self.tag_replace('BOXSELECT', tk.SEL)
    
    #reset    
    def __boxreset(self) -> None:
        #clean up box-select generated whitespace
        self.__boxclean()
        #turn off box-select
        self.__boxselect = False
        #reset bounds
        self.__lbounds   = None
        
    #remove any whitespace that box-select created  
    def __boxclean(self) -> None:
        if b:=self.__lbounds:
            #store current caret position
            p = self.caret
            for n in range(b.br, b.er+1): 
                #right strip this line
                text = self.get(f'{n}.0', f'{n}.end').rstrip()
                #replace this line with the stripped text
                self.replace_text(f'{n}.0', f'{n}.end', text)
                #put the caret back where it was
                self.caret = p
            #so things don't get froggy
            self.focus_set()
     
    #update __lbounds (w)ith (g)rab (o)ffsets
    def __boxmove(self, wgo:bool=True) -> SelectBounds:
        if b:=self.__lbounds:
            r, c = map(int, self.caret.split('.'))
            #update bounds
            if self.__boxselect:
                r = r if not wgo else max(1, r+self.__hgrabofs)
                self.__lbounds = self.__bounds(f'{r}.{c}', f'{r+b.h}.{c+b.w}', ow=True)
            #normal select
            else:
                self.__lbounds = self.__bounds(f'{r}.{c}', self.index(f'{r}.{c}+{b.w}c'), ow=True)
                
        return self.__lbounds

    #CLIPBOARD
    #restore clipboard data to last clipboard
    def __restore_clipboard(self) -> None:
        if self.__lclipbd:
            self.clipboard_clear()
            self.clipboard_append(self.__lclipbd)

    #remove every selection-related thing 
    def __cut(self, p:str=None):
        #make sure the widget is paying attention
        self.focus_set()
        #get selection ranges
        r = self.tag_ranges(tk.SEL)
        for i in range(0, len(r), 2):
            self.tag_remove(tk.SEL, *r[i:i+2])  #remove tk.SEL tag
            self.replace_text(*r[i:i+2], '')    #remove selected text
        self.caret = p or self.caret            #put the caret somewhere
        
    #move all selected text to clipboard
    def __copy(self) -> None:
        #make sure the widget is paying attention
        self.focus_set()
        #get selection ranges
        r = self.tag_ranges(tk.SEL)
        #compile clipboard data from ranges
        t = '\n'.join(self.get(*r[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(r),2))
        if t:
            #bkup, clear and populate clipboard
            #bkup used with boxmove to restore the clipboard after the move
            try               : self.__lclipbd = self.clipboard_get()
            except tk.TclError: self.__lclipbd = ''
            self.clipboard_clear()
            self.clipboard_append(t)

    #insert clipboard text
    def __paste(self, side:str=tk.LEFT) -> None:
        #get lines
        l = self.clipboard_get().split('\n')
        #get caret row, col
        r,c = map(int, self.caret.split('.'))
        #insert each line at an incrementing row index
        for i,t in enumerate(l):
            p = f'{r+i}.{c}'
            
            #if the row doesn't exist, create it
            if self.compare(p, '>=', 'end'):
                self.insert(tk.END, f'\n')
                
            #if the column doesn't exist, create it
            q = f'{r+i}.end'
            if self.compare(p, '>=', q) and i:
                #where are we really
                x,_,w,_ = self.bbox(f'{r}.{c}')
                #what's the difference in available and desired columns
                n = int(x//w)-int(self.index(q).split('.')[-1])
                #add enough space to keep us in line, and add the text while we are at it
                self.insert(q, f'{" "*(n)}{t}')
                continue
                    
            #insert (t)ext at (p)osition
            self.insert(p, t)
        
        #put the caret at the beginning
        if side==tk.LEFT: self.caret = f'{r}.{c}'
        #make sure the widget is paying attention
        self.focus_set()
    
    #EVENTS
    def __handler(self, event) -> None:
        if event.type == tk.EventType.KeyPress:
            if event.state & CONTROL:
                if event.keysym=='c':
                    #if not boxcopy, normal cut/copy/paste behaviors are used
                    self.__boxcopy = not self.__mouseisdown and self.__boxselect
                    
                    #BOXSELECT COPY(Cntl+c)
                    if self.__boxcopy:
                        self.__copy()
                        return 'break'
                        
                if event.keysym=='x':
                    #if not boxcopy, normal cut/copy/paste behaviors are used
                    self.__boxcopy = not self.__mouseisdown and self.__boxselect
                    
                    #BOXSELECT CUT(Cntl+x)
                    if self.__boxcopy:
                        self.__copy()
                        self.__cut()
                        return 'break'
                          
                if event.keysym=='v':
                    #BOXSELECT PASTE(Cntl+v)
                    if self.__boxcopy:
                        #if there is a selection to paste over, destroy it
                        self.__cut()
                        #set caret to begin position
                        if b:=self.__lbounds: self.caret = f'{b.br}.{b.bc}'
                        self.__paste()
                        self.__boxreset()    
                        return 'break'
                #   
                if event.keysym in ('Left','Right','KP_Left','KP_Right'):
                    #get tag .start, .end
                    b, e = self.tag_bounds(tk.SEL)
                    #remove tk.SEL tag
                    self.tag_move(tk.SEL)
                    #reset box-select
                    self.__boxreset()
                    #set caret to begin or end position based on relevant key
                    if b and e: self.caret = e if 'Right' in event.keysym else b
                    return 'break'
        
            #Shift+Alt regardless of keypress order
            self.__hotbox = (event.keysym in ('Alt_L'  ,'Alt_R'  )) and (event.state & SHIFT) or \
                            (event.keysym in ('Shift_L','Shift_R')) and (event.state & ALT)
                               
            #BOXSELECT
            if self.__hotbox:
                if event.state & BUTTON1:
                    #box-select mousedown
                    if not self.__mouseisdown:
                        #turn on box-select switches
                        self.__boxselect   = True
                        self.__mouseisdown = True
                        #store last known 'insert' index (ie. NOT 'current')
                        self.__boxstart  = self.__linsert
                        return 'break'
                    
                    #box-select mousemove
                    self.__boxend = self.caret
                            
                    #if the new bounds differ from the last bounds
                    if (nb:=(self.__bounds())) != (lb:=(self.__lbounds)):
                        #remove added whitespace from last call
                        self.__boxclean()
                        
                        #prime begin and end ranges
                        b, e = [], []
                        
                        #store new ranges and adjust line
                        for n in range(nb.br, nb.er+1):
                            #store beginning and end indexes
                            b.append(f'{n}.{nb.bc}')
                            e.append(f'{n}.{nb.ec}')
                            
                            #get difference in selection width
                            diff = nb.ec-int(self.index(f'{n}.end').split('.')[-1])
                            
                            #add spaces, if necessary
                            if diff>0: self.insert(f'{n}.end', ' '*diff)
                        
                        #reassign tag ranges
                        self.tag_move('BOXSELECT', b, e)
                        #store new bounds
                        self.__lbounds = nb
                    
                    #suppress built-in behavior
                    return 'break'
                        
                #bake-in 'BOXSELECT' as tk.SEL                
                if self.__mouseisdown: self.__hotswap()
                
                #store 'insert' position before button1 press
                self.__linsert = self.caret
                
                #suppress built-in behavior
                return 'break'
                    
        elif event.type == tk.EventType.KeyRelease:
            #"bake in" selection
            if self.__hotbox and (event.keysym in ('Alt_L','Alt_R','Shift_L','Shift_R')): 
                #swap BOXSELECT for tk.SEL
                self.__hotswap()
                #suppress built-in behavior
                return 'break'
            
        elif event.type == tk.EventType.ButtonPress:
            #get mouse index
            m  = self.index('current') 
            
            #GRAB SELECTED
            #check if mouse index is within a selection
            if tk.SEL in self.tag_names(m):
                #if this is a normal selection
                if not self.__lbounds:
                    #create bounds for the selection ~ overwrite boxstart/boxend with min/max indexes
                    self.__lbounds  = self.__bounds(*self.tag_bounds(tk.SEL), ow=True)
                    
                #flip tk.SEL to BOXSELECT
                self.tag_replace(tk.SEL, 'BOXSELECT')
                #turn off all tag add/remove except BOXSELECT in .__proxy
                self.__seldrag = True
                #4-way arrows
                self['cursor'] = 'fleur'
                
                if b:=self.__lbounds:
                    #get mouse index row
                    r,_ = map(int, m.split('.'))
                    #store horizontal grab offset
                    self.__hgrabofs = b.br-r
                    
            #if a selection is not under the mouse, reset
            elif self.__boxselect: self.__boxreset()
                
        elif event.type == tk.EventType.ButtonRelease:
            #DROP SELECTED
            if self.__seldrag:
                #regular cursor
                self['cursor'] = 'xterm'
                
                #COPY
                #turn on all tag add/remove in __proxy
                self.__seldrag = False
                #flip BOXSELECT back to tk.SEL
                self.tag_replace('BOXSELECT', tk.SEL)
                #copy
                self.__copy()
                
                #cut and paste
                if bnd:=self.__boxmove(): # move bounds to current location
                    #CUT
                    #this tracks any effect a deletion has on where we are trying to drop this
                    self.mark_set(INSPNT, (self.caret, f'{bnd.br}.{bnd.bc}')[self.__boxselect])
                    #delete selection and move caret to insertion point
                    self.__cut(INSPNT)
                    
                    #PASTE NORMAL
                    if not self.__boxselect:                  
                        self.event_generate('<<Paste>>')
                        #insertion point
                        ip = self.index(INSPNT)
                        #the caret is always at the end of a regular paste
                        self.__lbounds = self.__bounds(ip, self.caret, ow=True)
                        #draw selection  
                        self.tag_move(tk.SEL, ip, self.caret)
                        return 
                    
                    #PASTE COLUMN 
                    self.__paste()
                    #restore clipboard
                    self.__restore_clipboard()
                    #move bounds to caret ~ the caret is always at the beginning of a column-paste
                    bnd  = self.__boxmove(False)
                    #compile new ranges
                    b, e = [], []
                    for n in range(bnd.br, bnd.er+1):
                        b.append(f'{n}.{bnd.bc}')
                        e.append(f'{n}.{bnd.ec}')
                    #draw selection  
                    self.tag_move(tk.SEL, b, e)
                            
    
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure   (0, weight=1)
        (text := Text(self)).grid(sticky='nswe')
        text.insert(tk.END, f'aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd | eee | fff | ggg | hhh ||\n'*20)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, though it will require some work. The basic idea is to bind to `<ButtonPress-1>`, `<B1-Motion>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>`. In those bindings you'll have to keep track of where the cursor was when it was clicked and where it is when it is being dragged. You'll then have to compute which characters are within that bounding box, and add the `sel` tag to those characters individually.

This should be pretty straight-forward if you use a fixed width font with wrapping turned off. With a variable width font, and/or with wrapping allowed, the problem will get much harder. Ultimately, though, it boils down to doing a little math while the user drags the mouse.

For inspiration, you can see how someone did this in tcl/tk on the [block-select page on the tcler's wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8406).

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan for your help! I'm working the way you suggested, I hope I can post here a snippet of code as soon as possible. Thank you for the link too, I searched tcl/tk wiki but had no luck (maybe the right tag to look at was **block select** instead of **column select**)